# object have different position when rendered than in 3d view

Tags: rendering, objects, rigging

i have a problem with my render, the object (floor) have a different position when rendered cause "drowning" the character.. guys did you know what is the problem?

note : the object floor doesn't have any key frames or anything and already applied the location

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's not floor position is changing, but the characters position. It's hard to say without checking the file.

Comment: nope from the camera view i think it's obvious the floor are changing not the character.. do you know website that i can upload the blend file?

Comment: There are lots of them ,but I've noticed, that most of users of stackexchange uses this one:http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Do you have any modifiers in the floor?